# Getting Error CS1503: "Argument 1: Cannot convert from 'System.Diagnostics,PerformanceCounter' to 'int'

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-code

I'm writing a UI based application in WPF on VSCode. Im trying to have the hardware performance specs update labels on the UI but i'm met with the error when i try to hand-off the total CPU Usage from PerformanceCounter to BackgroundWorker so it can update the UI accordingly in a separate thread

Here's the code-behind the window I intend on displaying the Hardware stats

Monitor.xaml.cs

```
public partial class Hostile_Monitor : Window
    {
        readonly BackgroundWorker bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

        PerformanceCounter PerfCPUCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Processor Information", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
        PerformanceCounter PerfCPUFreqCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Processor Information", "Processor Frequency", "_Total");
        PerformanceCounter PerfMemCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");

        public Hostile_Monitor()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //Create Backgroundwroker Object
            bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
            //Add DoWork EventHandler
            bgWorker.DoWork += BackgroundWorker1_DoWork;
            //Progress changed EventHandler
            bgWorker.ProgressChanged += BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged;
            //RunWorkerCompleted EventHandler
            //bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted;
            //Allow to be cancelled
            bgWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            //allow to report progress
            bgWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

            private void BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        { 
            for (int i = 1; i > 0; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                bgWorker.ReportProgress(PerfCPUCounter);  // This line is where the error occurs @->(PerfCPUCounter);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

                if (bgWorker.CancellationPending)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Thread is exiting...");
                    break;
                }
            }
         }

        private void BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Label1.Content = e.ProgressPercentage;

        private void ButtonPower_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (bgWorker.IsBusy)
            {
                bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
                ButtonPower.Content = "Stop Monitor";
            } else
            {
                bgWorker.CancelAsync();
                ButtonPower.Content = "Start Monitor";
            }
```

This is my first attempt at developing a desktop application so any tips would be greatly appreciated
Hopefully i included all necessary code for you guys to get an idea of what's going on

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
bgWorker.ReportProgress((int)Math.Round( PerfCPUCounter.NextValue()))
```

Comment: I tried implementing your fix and it threw another error at the same place "Cannot convert from Float to Int" 

            for (int i = 1; i > 0; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                bgWorker.ReportProgress(PerfCPUCounter.NextValue());   

//Error persists here @ -> (perfCPUCounter.NextValue()

Comment: @HostileOperator I updated my answer, try again.

Comment: That resolved the error i was getting, thank you! I appreciate your help! Now to figure out how to make the Label update with the stats!